# Merging arrays in a list python

Tags: python, list, standard-deviation

I have 8 data files each with column and length

```
file=glob.glob('*.txt')

x=0
plotnum=1
LL=[]

for f in file: 
    A=np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=2, usecols=[0]) #column with area data
    L=np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=2, usecols=[1]) #column with length data

.......#code that plots subplots, calculates best fit lines, prints equations etc

LL.append(L)

plotnum+=1
x+=1
```

at the end of the loop when I print LL it prints out a list of arrays. I need to calculate the standard deviation of all the data but this shows up with an error when I type:

```
np.std(LL)
```

is there a way to merge all the arrays into a single list so I can then calculate the standard deviation?

Comment: dude ... can you show the error?

Comment: `np.std(LL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2836, in std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 125, in _std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 92, in _var
    arrmean = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, keepdims=True)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,) (93,)`

Comment: and also want see a print LL

Comment: I recommend you that show the information of your txt, and see it https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html may be help you

Comment: LL is way too long to add to comments so I've shortened it where 1,2,3 etc is a list of numbers: 
`>>> LL [array([1]), array([2]), array([3]), array([4]), array([5]), array([6]), array([7]), array([2])]`
the problem is in the loop each time 1,2,3 etc is called L each time

Comment: @Rcoder Please use the edit link under the question to add more details to the question, rather than posting more details in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
full_list = []
for sublist in LL;
    full_list.extend(sublist)
```

Will merge the individual lists into one big list of all the values

Comment: thanks the extend function did the job! In my loop changed LL.append(L) to LL.extend(L) and at the end when I printed LL all the data was merged into one long list.